# SVN plugin issue in eclipse

Tags: eclipse, svn, tortoisesvn, soa

I have installed SVN plugin to my eclipse by 'Help->Install new software'. Used the URL - http://subclipse.tigris.org/update_1.6.x.

After installation, I tried connect my SVN URL(http://svnserver.com/svn) which worked others machine in tortaise svn. It got prompted with credentials, then it ended up with below error message in eclipse.

`RA layer request failed
svn: Server sent unexpected return value (500 Internal Server Error) in response to OPTIONS request for 'http://svnserver.com/svn'`

Note : I have connected client network in citrix (Cisco anyclient) after disabling the proxy in my machine.

Eclipse platform is v3.6.3

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved my issue by adding host under proxy bypass in Window->preference->General->Network connections(Active provider = Manual).

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that the SVN plug-in installed in Eclipse is up to date and that the entered URL is correct. Generally speaking, the error `500 Internal Server Error` indicates a problem with the server. However, invalid repository URL might also produce such error in certain cases.